# Weird rendering with Three.js R69

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have weird rendering effect with http://i62.tinypic.com/2li7hb6.jpg with the latest release of Three.js library, it seems that there is not any depth perception for torus and sphere in scene, torus and sphere is overlapped by the grid, which was not supposed to be.

I'm not sure whether it's due to the malfunctioning in graphic card dirver or with wrong settings of scene, but normally with previous release Three.js R68 there was not required any configuration to make depth aware the scene engine.

Aside from the facts listed above, I have recently bought computer which has AMD Radeon R7 M260 graphic card installed, so I'm not sure whether all of this is due to that graphic card driver or some wrong settings Three.js.

Regards,

Comment: without any code to verify that the grid should be behind the sphere and the torus or that the renderer and the materials were setup correctly, thre is no way to help you. If you want us to verify that the problem is not related to graphics card, create a jsfiddle with the problem.

Comment: I didn't add any single line of code in original "editor" folder of github-Three.js distrubition, so its a original R69 release. If I still have to add that to fiddle, I'm bit of dubious whether it will accept the whole files.

Comment: Try `WebGLRenderer` in the Editor.

Comment: Interestingly I don't have webGLrenderer in dropdown list in renderer section. IMHO that proves that there is malfunctioning in hardware level. I downloaded the very same R69 version on another machine which has Nvidia and it produced the expected results, where there was also WebGLrenderer option.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the grid not play the game of z-testing like other objects, is because of two separated scenes in the Three.js editor. there is regular scene that contain your sphere and torus, and another scene named sceneHelpers that aim for visual aids like bounding box, modifiers arrow, and the grid.

Comment: reference (line 16): https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/editor/js/Viewport.js#L16